# Did Hamas kill Israeli babies during the October 7 2023 attacks on Israel?

Tags: israel, israel-hamas-war

In [another question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/56115/were-babies-found-with-their-heads-decapitated-in-israel-after-the-hamas-attack), the topic of whether babies were beheaded in the October 7 attack by Hamas on Israel is addressed.

Putting aside the specific claims of beheadings, allegedly some accounts are saying no babies were killed by Hamas at all. (This [BBC article](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-middle-east-67206277) quotes some anonymously, but suggests they are false.]

Did Hamas kill babies during their rampage?

Comment: The beheadings claim was not shown to be an exaggeration, it was shown to be  baseless . Please edit to reflect that. Otherwise, you seem to be pushing that claim through the new question.

Comment: Can you please define what exactly you mean by *murder*?  Are babies killed due to Hamas rockets included, or do you mean specifically killing a baby (such as with a bullet from a short range)?

Comment: I'm sure that there's some denialism from the Hamas side (there was one official who said something like that, but I can't find that right now), but the Hinkle link you gave isn't that, explicitly. He just claims there that one photo was doctored or was showing something else than claimed. So I think you need some better examples, with quotes, to meet the Skeptics standards for questions. (Hinkle is an Assad apologist, by the way.)

Comment: Make that "two photos". Both tweets are from him. In the latter, he claims that one of the photos shown by Netanyahu (although he only links to a Ben Shapiro post) were "AI generated". This is probably closer to plain denialism.

Comment: BTW, Hinkle might not have originated that latter claim. There's a Chinese (Singaporean to be more precise) vlogger who claims to have run an analysis. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2pGOyL7jCQA It's probably bullshit, but I don't have the expertise to debunk his technical claims.

Comment: More direct link to the their "analysis" https://defensepoliticsasia.com/israel-published-ai-generated-photo-of-burnt-charred-baby-as-hamas-victim/

Comment: @gerrit the latter. Specific murder, not collateral damage.

Comment: @TheAsh: Neither of your links made the claim that *no* Israeli children were killed by Hamas. Please give an example of such a claim.

Comment: @gerrit: The OP's definition is irrelevant. It is the *claimant's* definition, and there is no claimant.

Comment: @Oddthinking, doesn't the Israeli claim that kids and babies were murdered (or killed) enough to justify the question? We don't need to show that there are notable skepticism of a claim for it to be relevant.

Comment: @SIMEL: Kind of, yes, but we need to heavily edit the question and invalidate some answers to match that, depending what version of the claim you link. The claim the OP says people are making - zero babies - is at an extreme end and relatively easy to address, compared to one that says "1,400 Israelis died, including many children, according to the IDF" that is likely unanswerable.

Comment: @Oddthinking, the latter claim will be answerable once all the names of the victims are published. Then it's a simple matter of counting the number of dead, and of them the number of children. It's just a matter of time. There might be that some will be missing and their body not found, and the abducted will need to be addressed (hopefully they will be released by then) but when enough time passes this question will be easily answerable.

Comment: @Oddthinking I can trivially find some accounts claiming or implying no babies were targeted by Hamas. Will editing them in ok the question? (TBF, the primary motivator of my question was the beheaded babies claim. I was curious if 40 or so babies were killed in any way, because the argument about beheading was getting ridiculous.)

Comment: @Oddthinking: I think I found something closer to whole cloth denialism https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qvJw7uT_zYE Unfortunately, there's a lot of back and forth between them and deflection from the Hamas guy to other topics (Israel killing children of course), so it's hard to select/transcribe a quote. Maybe if you're patient...

Comment: @Oddthinking: I managed to find the vid of the original "shocked" guy https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Egipqa0ZhUk who said Hamas didn't kill any *civlians*. That's so preposterous though that I'm not sure it's worthy of a Q here.

Comment: @Fizz: I patiently listened to the first interview. I didn't hear the claim.

Comment: @Fizz: The second interview (which was chronologically first) consisted of the Hamas spokesperson denying *civilians* had been killed, and then clarified that he was using an unconventional definition of "civilians" to exclude settlers (presumably including babies). So there is no claim that there were no babies killed.

Comment: @TheAsh: Yes, please edit them in - especially the ones that specifically make the claim that no babies were killed.

Comment: @Oddthinking: I see, I did not have patience to watch the whole thing.

Comment: @Oddthinking https://twitter.com/RyLiberty/status/1713864180384899295

Comment: @Oddthinking https://twitter.com/Lucas_Gage_/status/1712512316577628235

Comment: @Oddthinking https://twitter.com/urtataamun/status/1714313912370208990

Comment: Thanks, @TheAsh: This has confirmed what I thought. Two of these tweets are saying the story about the 40 beheaded babies isn't true (covered by another question) and the last is questioning the death of baby in a particular photo (now removed). No-one cited is claiming "No babies were killed", so the existing answers to this question are all tackling a strawman that the original question posed.

Comment: @Oddthinking: Hmm, the Lucas Gage tweet is more specific "Do we have any videos of Israelis pulling dead babies out from any rubble? Or them bringing babies to the hospital?" Of course it is a bit a case of moving the goalposts, so not chaging the Q to that quote after answers have been given is probably the right decision.

Comment: @Oddthinking: what about this "Several accounts that supported Hamas claimed that Omer had been a "paid actor" because **Hamas "didn't kill kids"**. Others said this was "Jewish propaganda at its finest", declaring that neither Omer, nor his sisters, had been killed. One wrote "there's no evidence" they were dead and asked to "stop the lying"." https://www.bbc.com/news/world-middle-east-67206277

Comment: @Fizz: Tricky given the article debunks the claim and they don't cite their sources of people who said that. Is it notable if one person says it on Twitter and it gets reported as false by the BBC?

Comment: @Oddthinking my main impetus for this question was the 40 babies claim - whether forty babies were killed in any matter (even if not beheaded). Should I reask that as a separate question?

Comment: There have been many more denials since this question has been asked.

Answer (score 25):

Yes.

**Second Edit:** As of Jan. 30<sup>th</sup>, the youngest victim is [less than a day old unnamed girl, the daughter of Tripi and S. Abu Rashed, from Abu Karinat bedouin tribe](https://twitter.com/IshmaelKhaldi/status/1731283544985469354). S. (the mother) was shot by Hamas terrorists on her way to the hospital to give birth to her girl. She was shot in her torso, one bullet hit the unborn child. When they reached the hospital the child was delivered and died later the same day. Her parents and uncle survived. [A Hebrew article](https://www.davar1.co.il/470107/) with more details.

Also, Omer Kedem Siman Tov was [2 years and 3 months old](https://twitter.com/nirhasson/status/1731371502144978984), not as previously reported, 4. Fixed in body.

**Edit:** As of Oct. 28<sup>th</sup>, the youngest victim whos name was released is [10 months old Mila Cohen](https://www.jns.org/three-generations-wiped-out-by-hamas-in-kibbutz-beeri/) who was murdered in her home.

At this time, not all the bodies have been identified, and of those that were not all names were released to the public. Of those whose names were released the youngest are Omer kedem siman tov, aged [2](https://twitter.com/nirhasson/status/1731371502144978984), who was [massacred with his entire family](https://www.smh.com.au/world/middle-east/they-told-friends-in-sydney-they-were-safe-then-this-entire-family-was-massacred-20231009-p5eayv.html). And Yazan Zakaria Abu Jama, an Arab Bedouin boy aged 5, who was killed when a [Hamas missile hit near his home](https://www.timesofisrael.com/always-the-first-to-defend-the-israelis-slain-in-hamass-surprise-onslaught/).

Beside these we have photographic evidence of Babies bodies from the attacks released by the IsraelPM twitter (X) account. **Warning, graphic images**

`https://x.com/IsraeliPM/status/1712471782303867144?s=20`

And finally we have first hand accounts of Zaka volunteers who collected and treated the bodies and remains of the murdered. Just one example from an [interview with a Zaka volunteer](https://x.com/kann_news/status/1712778343903367355?s=20) depicting what he personally witnessed in Be'eri:

> We found families that were simply shot to death. Some of them burned to death after they murdered them. We had to care for bodies of children and babies. They didn't distinguish between anyone they just went around and killed anybody they saw in front of them. We saw children, we saw small bags with babies inside.

As time will pass, more bodies will be identified and their names will be released to the public we will have a clear picture of the exact number of babies that were killed. But the proofs that babies were killed are irrefutable.

In addition to murdering babies, Hamas has also taken several kids and babies hostages. The youngest is [Kfir Bibs, only 9 mounth old](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-middle-east-67064742).

Comment: Is there any truth to the rumors of the nursery?

Comment: @TheAsh, what exactly? Is the picture real? I believe so. There are many pictures and video footage made by the terrorist themselves in real time of the murders there is no need for fakery. Is the blood in the picture of a baby? I don't know, maybe, it can also be an older kid, a parent, a soldier that died liberating that house. Even the blood of a Hamas terrorist who was killed in the house by IDF. After all, we all bleed the same color, except for Hinkle, as a Nazi, his veins are filled with sewage. But the message of the picture, that kids and babies were murdered is absolutely true.

Comment: I am referring to the rumors that hamas killed 40 babies in one nursery.

Comment: @TheAsh: Sounds like it should be a separate question.

Comment: When people are killed without premeditation of getting _them_ killed, e.g. by a bomb being dropped somewhere populated, or by inaccurate artillery fire into some region, that's not a murder. So, Israel is (for the most part) not murdering civilians in Gaza, it is killing them. Gazan fighters indeed have killed quite a number of Israelis by means of rockets etc. The question is whether they _murdered_ babies. That would typically mean fighters who encounter a baby, specifically decide to kill them, and do so. That is not to say that this didn't happen, because it may very well have.

Comment: Going into a house and specifically shooting a bullet through a baby (which a 4-year-old isn't IMHO) is not the same as shooting rockets at houses killing everyone inside, which happens to include babies.

Comment: @einpoklum - That seems a distinction without a moral difference. Indeed, in many jurisdictions, there exists a crime like "depraved-heart murder" (USA) or "Eventualvorsatz" (Germany), where killing someone due to an act that was foreseeably perilous to the lives of others can be considered murder even without the specific intention to kill them. To me, the actions of Hamas and the IDF would constitute such a murder even if one buys that they do not want civilian casualties (something I personally am skeptical of, having heard some of the dehumanizing rhetoric that they are using).

Comment: @einpoklum, This is exactly what happened to 4 years old Omer and his family. Terrorists entered their house and murdered them.

Comment: @gerrit, 4 years old is the youngest person whos name was released. We have photographic evidence and first hand accounts of babies being killed, literal infants. Their names have not been released to the public yet either because they weren't identified, or their families weren't informed yet.

Comment: @Obie2.0 Sending rockets at a country that is militarily occupying ones own is an act of war, and might be a war crime if civilians are targeted deliberately.  Running around massacring civilians (with or without including children) is quite clearly a war crime, whether it's Hamas in Israel or Russia in Bucha.  The latter is conventionally called murder, but I'm not sure if that's true for the former. If Hamas rockets killing Israeli civilians constitute murder, then so do Russian rockets killing Ukrainian civilians or American rockets killing Yemeni wedding guests.

Comment: @SIMEL check if the hidden link is still working.

Comment: @TheAsh, the original claim wasn't that 40 babies were murdered in the same nursery, but that they were murdered in the same Kibbutz (Kfar Aza), and that some of them were beheaded. We need to remember the situation and time when this claim was made, still in the fog of war, still under fire, still in a state of shock. Time will tell how many kids were killed in Kfar Aza, but I personally would accept this claim as true if a high number of kids including babies were killed there. As this was made from eye witness account at real time, not by an official after all the facts were known.

Comment: @DavePhD, alll links work for me. you can also find it on the `@IsraelPM` twitter account dated to October 12.

Comment: @SIMEL thanks, I tried again after logging in to twitter and it worked.

Comment: @gerrit - I am perfectly willing to call those American and Russian actions murder under the same reasoning.

Comment: I removed all mention of murder from the question, because there was no evidence anyone claimed murder. Murder typically refers to a legal definition, and is determined by a court of law.

Comment: How do we know these children weren't killed by IDF crossfire?

Comment: @Abdullah, depends for each case. In the case of the three babies named in my answer the circumstances of their death is mentioned in the articles linked. A tl;dr: Yazan Zakaria Abu Jama the Bedouin boy was killed by a Hamas rocket, no IDF fire near him. Omer kedem siman tov was massacred with his entire family in their home long before IDF came to Nir Oz(their Kibbutz), and Mila Cohen was gunned down when Hamas fired at their shelter door, as described by her Mother who survived, again long before the IDF reached Be'eri. And Kfir Bibs was kidnapped to Gaza, surely not by the IDF.

Comment: "As time will pass, more bodies will be identified and their names will be released to the public we will have a clear picture of the exact number of babies that were killed." As of this writing only one baby name has been released, Mila Cohen. Your answer strongly implies that there probably is (many) more which appears to not be the case.

Comment: @StandwithGaza, the update of Mila Cohen's name was after the line. We still don't know the status of Kfir Bibs that PIJ claim is dead but provided no confirmation of this. And TTBOMK not all names bodies were identified and thus not all names released. We might not get a full list of all the dead before the destruction of Hamas and release of all hostages and bodies held by them. Even if Mila is the only child under 1 year old who was murdered on 7/10, the answer is still yes, Hamas murdered babies on 7/10.

Comment: @DanRomik, thanks for that, found the source. I'll fix this and add the baby girl who was born and then died after her pregnant mother was shot.

Comment: @SIMEL  You need to update your answer to add a disclaimer to the Zaka testimony.

Comment: @Ona what disclaimer exactly?

Comment: @SIMEL that current official numbers do not support that quote (how is it possible to find small bags of babies in Be'eri) when only Mila is there (both tov and the 14-hour baby are somewhere else). and that Haaretz ran stories disproving it

Comment: @Ona That is the reaction of a first responder to the scene. He could have mistaken the age of the bodies because of their state. He could have mistaken parts of bodies as babies. He could of also used babies as a broader term for kids in general and not necessarily stopping at a certain cutoff as in "Oh no, he was 1 year and 2 days old, he's not a baby, that's obviously a toddler, and she's not a kid, she was 10 and a half so she is a teenager". In short, I'm not putting that disclaimer, especially since that testimony has now lesser weight when we know the identities of murdered babies.

Comment: @SIMEL "That is the reaction of a first responder to the scene. He could have mistaken the age of the bodies because of their state" this phrase is exactly what I'm asking you to add to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The [Times of Israel](https://www.timesofisrael.com/14-kids-under-10-25-people-over-80-up-to-date-breakdown-of-oct-7-victims-we-know-about/) reported in late December that Israeli
authorities had identified 274 soldiers and 859 non-soldiers killed on
October 7. Of them two babies and twelve other children under the age
of 15. However, the Israeli governments [list of Israeli civilian
casualties](https://www.gov.il/en/departments/news/swords-of-iron-civilian-casualties) only names one baby - Mila Cohen. She was shot through
the door to their house's safe room by militants, according to [The
Cradle](https://thecradle.co/articles/israeli-army-police-repeat-false-claims-of-hamas-atrocities). [Haaretz](https://www.haaretz.com/israel-news/2023-12-04/ty-article-magazine/.premium/hamas-committed-documented-atrocities-but-a-few-false-stories-feed-the-deniers/0000018c-34f3-da74-afce-b5fbe24f0000) reported that the fetus of a mother who was
shot did not survive so probably that's where the second "baby" comes
from. It's also possible, albeit perhaps less likely, that Mila Cohen
was double-counted or that one baby has not been identified yet.

Baby (infant) here defined as a child younger than twelve months,
which is how the American [CDC](https://www.cdc.gov/ncbddd/childdevelopment/positiveparenting/infants.html) defines the word. According to
victim lists, none other than Mila Cohen and the fetus/unborn child
were younger than two years so how "baby" is defined is not critical.

In the aftermath of the attack Israel's prime minister tweeted photos
of what he claimed were charred remains of burned babies and the US
president [repeatedly claimed](https://theintercept.com/2023/12/14/israel-biden-beheaded-babies-false/) to have seen photos of
decapitated babies. The [Israeli army claimed](https://twitter.com/IDF/status/1716462311370633484) to have a photo of a
"pregnant woman next to her beheaded unborn baby cut out of her
belly". These claims are difficult to reconcile with the fact that
only one or two babies (depending on how you count) has been identified.

Comment: I am not sure why you suggest the Times of Israel may have double-counted, when they (and the Israeli government) explicitly mention the death of the baby who was delivered after the 9-month pregnant woman was shot.

Comment: Because whether a fetus is a "baby" (or "infant") or not is a hotly debated topic. But sure, it is possible that explains why it says two babies were killed.

Comment: @StandwithGaza they may have been counting the two years old.

Comment: @StandwithGaza great unbiased answer - despite the username.

Comment: @StandwithGaza: While I acknowledge there is room for disagreement about terms, the Israeli Government version made it clear the mother was 9 months pregnant when she was shot and the child was delivered in an emergency procedure and lived for 14 hours. (I am unclear whether the mother was alive during the birth.)  I think it is far more prosaic to suggest that the media described the child as a baby than they double-counted.

Comment: Why are you using  a source that is 2 months old instead of a current one, when those are readily available? Baby is not a rigid definition, there is no reason to define a baby as only 1 year olds, baby is a small child, with some internet sources go as high as 4 years old.

Comment: Also, the Cradle's bias is seen a mile away. Its is doing its best to deliberately misrepresent the truth. They cling to the claim that there is no Holocaust survivor named "Genia"  who was killed on Oct 7, disregarding Moshe Ridler, the 91 Holocaust survivor who was murdered (together with his caretaker). They cling to "no 9 kids were killed together in Be'eri" while casually mentioning that more than 100 of Be'eri residents were killed as if it's normal and shouldn't be regarded at all.

Comment: @Oddthinking, the mother survived and was released from the hospital after two days.

Comment: @SIMEL: Oh, that a little good news from a larger tragedy. Thank you.

Comment: Oddthinking Fair enough. Changed answer to reflect that. @SIMEL I couldn't find any newer source than
ToI that conveniently groups victims into children and *babies*.

Comment: @SIMEL "the claim that there is no Holocaust survivor named "Genia" who was killed on Oct 7," But that's true. There was no holocaust survivor named Gina. and no holocaust survivor in Be'eri either. Moshe Ridler was killed in Holit.

Comment: @Ona, it's true, there was Genia, but it is not of any real weight and doesn't change the overall picture. Those are small details which is perfectly understandable that some of them were wrong when the first testimonies were collected. Like the fact that Omer Kedem Siman Tov was 2 years old and not 4 years old doesn't change any significate part. The fact that The Cradle use small and inconsequential errors to depict all the Oct 7 attack as false or to diminish its ferocity shows their clear bias and motivation.

Comment: updated data on the number of victims can be found here: https://www.gov.il/en/departments/news/swords-of-iron-war-in-the-south-7-oct-2023

Comment: Holocaust survivors are not *babies* so the discussion about them doesn't belong here. @Ona Your source claims that "babies were butchered" but only mentions the "unborn child" and not Mila Cohen. It contradicts the info in the Israeli government source I linked to in my answer.

Answer (score -2):

## There were 2 babies to 1 baby killed, but the underlying claim of mass-killing of babies is false.

[image: graphic based on the list of civilians published by Israeli ministry of foreign affairs]

As you can see in this graphic based on the [official list of civilians,](https://www.gov.il/en/Departments/news/swords-of-iron-civilian-casualties) published and updated  on 22.01.2024 by Israeli Ministry of Foreign Affairs.
There are 5 children under the age of 5:

| name | age | category | cause of death |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Mila Cohen (Kibbutz Be'eri) | 10 months old | baby | The family huddled together in their safe room as terrorists shot at the door, killing their 10-month-old daughter [JNS](https://www.jns.org/three-generations-wiped-out-by-hamas-in-kibbutz-beeri/) |
| Abu Qrenat baby (mother shot in Reim junction) | 14 hours old | Fetus (at time of shooting) / baby | In the terrorists' attack on them on October 7, his 23-year-old wife S. was shot in the abdomen. The bullet hit the leg of the fetus, which she had been carrying in her womb (hebrew: [davar1](https://www.davar1.co.il/470107/)) |
| Omer Siman Tov (Kibbutz Nir Oz) | 2 years and 3 months | toddler | killed in their family Bunker (I havent found the method) |
| Yazan Zecharia Abu Jama (Ar'ara) | 5 years | Pre-schooler | Rocket struck his home |
| Eitan Kapshetar (Sderot) | 5 years | Pre-schooler | Shot in the family car in Sderot, together with other family members |

**False Zaka Volunteer Testimony:**

The  following quote cited by @SIMEL is currently accepted to be  a False report,
as demonstarted through Haaretz's article: ["Hamas Committed Documented Atrocities. But a Few False Stories Feed the Deniers"](https://www.haaretz.com/israel-news/2023-12-04/ty-article-magazine/.premium/hamas-committed-documented-atrocities-but-a-few-false-stories-feed-the-deniers/0000018c-34f3-da74-afce-b5fbe24f0000), talking about Kibbutz Be'eri the volunteer says:

> We found families that were simply shot to death. Some of them burned to death after they murdered them. We had to care for bodies of children and babies. They didn't distinguish between anyone they just went around and killed anybody they saw in front of them. We saw children, we saw small bags with babies inside.

Namely, apart form Mila cohen, There haven't been any other victims in Be'eri under the age of  10. The next youngest children are 2 12 years old sisters Yanai and Liel Hezroni that died when IDF used 2 tank shells to bomb a house full of hostages and hostage takers. (The incident is discussed here:
[Survivors' testimony on tank fire, families' call for IDF probe- Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Be%27eri_massacre#Survivors%27_testimony_on_tank_fire,_families%27_call_for_IDF_probe)). So "small bags with babies inside" is  impossible to have happened.

A kibbutz spokesperson said:

> "Nearly one hundred people were murdered on Kibbutz Be'eri, and the community suffered hundreds of heartbreaking incidents on that Black Saturday and over the past months, especially regarding the hostages. However, incidents such as eight murdered babies and a murdered Holocaust survivor named Genia – did not happen." [Haaretz](https://www.haaretz.com/israel-news/2024-01-21/ty-article/.premium/army-officer-makes-incorrect-claims-on-oct-7-massacre-idf-well-set-record-straight/0000018d-2c67-daf5-a1bf-ac77f9b50000)

Trying to explain the testimonies, a Zaka leader speaks:
"Our volunteers were confronted with traumatic scenes and sometimes misinterpreted what they saw," said Otmazgin." [France 24](https://www.france24.com/en/live-news/20231215-israel-social-security-data-reveals-true-picture-of-oct-7-deaths)

<sup>for completeness victims for which age was not listed and couldn't be located are: 5 Nepali students, Sammi Jarjawi (Segev Shalom), Hatib Zaruk (Ofakim), Goytum Jabrahiwat (an asylum seeker) and 25 Thai workers. oct7map.com claims that Sammi Jarjawi  is 52 but does not give a reliable source</sup>

Comment: Unrelated to the answer but to avoid misunderstanding:  The spokesperson claim is "a person under the name of Gina did die, but she was not a holocaust survivor". Another  Holocaust survior of the age of 91 died in Kibbutz Holit (not Kibbutz Be'eri)