# Were multiple Israeli children found decapitated by Hamas on the same location and responders were trying to figure out which head belonged to whom?

Tags: mortality, israel, terrorism, hamas

[According](https://youtu.be/ssiiZW9e6xw?t=101) to [Eli Beer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eli_Beer) [interviewed on TBN], after the Hamas attack on Oct 7, Israeli first responders ran into a scene where multiple children had been decapitated on same location and "we were trying to figure out which head belongs to which child".

Beer makes exactly the same claim in another, much longer speech/video at the Republican Jewish Coalition Annual Leadership Summit (around [32:50](https://youtu.be/nKNPz51lTig?t=1959)) where he also implies he personally saw that scene:

> I saw little kids who were beheaded. We didn't know which head belonged to which kid.

Are the other accounts (and/or material evidence) confirming this event?

Note: there's a separate [question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/56115/were-babies-found-with-their-heads-decapitated-in-israel-after-the-hamas-attack) here about *any* decapitated babies. This claim is about children, so not the same (could be substantially older than babies), and furthermore the claim is that there was a mass decapitation of children in the same location.

Comment: I don't know about the specifics of this exact scenario. But in general there is a problem with identifying the victims and the bodies mainly because many were burned. There is a picture making it's rounds of a human burned and decapitated head (although it's not clear if it's an adult or a child) which would not allow identification without DNA samples or circumstantial evidence linking it to a specific person.

Comment: according to todays CNN video about the Israeli morgue, they still try haven't identified all the body parts https://edition.cnn.com/

Answer (score 7):

Oral surgeon Dr. Naama Samet Rubinstein said on [video](https://www.newsnationnow.com/video/israeli-surgeon-says-shes-witnessed-beheaded-babies-cut-off-limbs-dan-abrams-live/9119781/):

> I saw the beheaded also, of course, yes, and the burnt ones, we had to do a special CT for this head that we got.  You know, I had several separate heads that I got. And we had to do a special CT to try to find out who it was. I mean it was a big deal believe me, those separate heads.

But she doesn't specify the ages of the victims whose heads she was trying to identify.

Comment: May be worth adding that Hamas grouped some captives together before executing them and setting them on fire. I'm in a bit of rush right now, so don't have link handy to those reports. (I vaguely recall it was Vach who said that in one of his many interviews with the press.)